# Как в get запросе передать данные в контроллер

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

*VS* подчеркивает `idr` и пишет:

> The name 'idr' does not exist in the current context

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.edit').click(function () {
        idr = $(this).attr('data-id');
         $.get('@Url.Action("Edit", "Main", new { id = idr })',
            function (data) {
                $('#Table').html(data);
            });
    });
});
```

Не пойму, почему переменная не существует? Как правильно передать значение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь смешать код C# и JavaScript в одной строке. Вы задаёте url с помощью хелпера `Url. Action`, который выполняется на сервере и подставляется в текст вашего скрипта в виде строкового литерала. Разумеется сервер ничего не знает о JavaScript-переменной idr, которая в тот момент даже не существует. 
Попробуйте сделать например так:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("Edit", "Main")?id=' + idr
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение! Сам не сообразил

Answer (score 1):

Потому что это переменная javascript-a (клиентского кода), а не C# (серверного кода).

```
    var idr = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.get('@Url.Action("Edit", "Main")/' + idr,
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так должно быть

```
$(function () {
  var youUrl = 'mysite.com/ajax.php';
  $('.edit').on('click', function () {
    var idr = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.alax({
      url: youUrl,
      data: {id: idr},
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (data) {
        $('#Table').html(data);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне именно `Url.Action()` нужен был